# Implementing numeric pagination with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination

Hai guys,
        I have nearly 20 pages in my website .... Every page has a gridview which has thousands of records bind to it... Now i want to implement custom pagination to all those grids.... Guys can some one give a pagination class which can be reusable for all those pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not really going to get a one size fits all class to do this, thats why its called custom paging.

Just a rough guide as to how I have implemented this in the past.

Store the current page number somewhere Querystring/Session/Wherever

When you call your data method/stored procedure to ask for the data pass in the page number and amount of records per page you want.

ammend you stored procedure/data method to only return records in these bounds, it will also need to return a count of the total records so the application knows how many pages there are.

Here is simple example of how you could achieve paging in your stored procedures using SQL2005/2008 (Slightly more to it in 2000)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTowns
(
@OutTotalRecCount INT OUTPUT,
@CurrentPage INT,
@PageSize INT
)
AS

    SELECT * FROM     
     (
     SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TownName) AS Row, 
      TownId,
      TownName
     FROM Towns
     ) AS TownsWithRowNumbers
    WHERE  Row >= (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND Row <= @CurrentPage*@PageSize

    SELECT @OutTotalRecCount = COUNT(*) FROM Towns
```

Comment: Hai gavin thanks for ur reply... I ve already written this procedure i only want c# coding to geneate linkbuttons showing page nos....

Comment: There is a basic example of some VB code you could easily convert to control the link buttons here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sd_patel/CustomPagingInDataGrid11232005232703PM/CustomPagingInDataGrid.aspx

Comment: Hai Gavin your procedure helped me a lot and i want to use these data show paging links using c# and i would prefer stack overflow pagination.....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a "class", but here are a couple of links:

[.NET 3.5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/DataPagerGridView08012008123240PM/DataPagerGridView.aspx)

[.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510021915/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx)

p.s. If you use DataSet as your DataSource, paging and sorting is supported out of the box.